# proof of the principle of uniform boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

A set $X$ is balanced i.e., if $x\in X$ and $|\alpha|\leq 1$, then $\alpha x\in X$. I can't see why $B(0,r_0)$ is also a subset of $X_{n_0}$. Any help, please?

Comment: Suppose $z\in B(0,r_0)$, then both $x_0\pm z \in X_{n_0}$. As $X_{n_0}$ is balanced,$-x_0+z = -(x_0-z) \in X_{n_0}$. By convexity, so is $z=\frac{1}{2}[(x_0+z)+(-x_0+z)]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y \in B(0,r_0)$. Then $x_0\pm y \in B(x_0,r_0)$ so $\|Tx_0\pm Ty\| \leq n \,\forall T \in \mathcal A$. Now use the fact that $Ty=\frac {T(y+x_0)+T(y-x_0)} 2$ to see that $\|Ty\| \leq \frac {n+n}2= n$.